# Print module on a Views page?

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to have a print/pdf link (using the [print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module) displayed on a views page?

I've got it displaying in a basic page type, but view is not a content type, so how do I select the option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Drupal 7 go to *admin/config/user-interface/print*, and add that page's (page created by view) path to the the list of system (non-content) pages in the Advanced Link Options tab.

[image: snapshot]

This will show the link on that page. For Drupal 6 the path is *admin/settings/print*.

Comment: Thank you @Indrock

I had the path set in the Link visibility and it didn't work but setting it in the non-content pages section did the trick.

Comment: Sorry @Indrock
Another question, is there a way to display the Print icon/link only after the search in the view has been performed? As in, the search displays results in the table format, is there a way for me to display the print link only if there are search results?